# Is there a way to automate specific data extraction from a number of pdf files and add them to an excel sheet?

Tags: python, vba, excel, pdf

Regularly I have to go through a list of pdf files and search for specific data and add them to an excel sheet for later review. As the number of pdf files are around 50 per month, it is both time taking and frustrating to do it manually.

Can the process be automated in windows by python or any other scripting language? I require to have all the pdf files in a folder and run the script which will generate an excel sheet with all the data added. The pdf files with which I work are tabular and have similar structures.

Comment: The answer is yes, take a look at this for VBA : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184595/loop-on-all-files-in-the-same-directory-then-detect-extension-type/29187762#29187762
You'll be able to detect all the files, open only pdf and then get the info inside!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. And no. And maybe.

The problem here is not extracting *something* from a PDF document. Extracting *something* is almost always possible and there are plenty of tools available to extract content from a PDF document. Text, images, whatever you need.

The major problem (and the reason for the "no" or "maybe") is that PDF in general is not a structured file format. It doesn't care about columns, paragraphs, tables, sentences or even words. In the general case it cares only about characters on a page in a specific location.

This means that in the general case you cannot query a PDF document and ask it for every paragraph or for the third sentence in the fifth paragraph. You can ask a library to get all of the text or all of the text in a specific location. And then you have to hope the library is able to extract the text you need in a legible format. Because there doesn't even have to be the case that you can copy and paste or otherwise extra understandable characters from a PDF file. Many PDF files don't even contain enough information for that.

So... If you have a certain type of document and you can test that it predictably behaves a certain way with a certain extraction engine, then yes, you can extract information from a PDF file.

If the PDF files you receive are different all the time or the layout on the page is totally different every time than the answer is probably that you cannot reliably extract the information you want.

**As a side note:**
There are certain types of PDF documents that are easier to handle than others so if you're lucky that might make your life easier. Two examples:

1. Many PDF files *will* in fact contain textual information in such a way that it can be extracted in a legible way. PDF files that follow certain standards (such as PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2a or PDF/A-2u etc...) are even required to be created this way.
2. Some PDF files are "tagged" which means they contain additional structural information that allows you to extract information in an easier and more meaningful way. This structure would in fact identify paragraphs, images, tables etc and if the tagging was done in a good way it could make the job of content extraction much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pdf2text2](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/#pdf2txt) in Python to extract data from your PDF.

Alternatively you can use `pdftotext` that is part of the [Xpdf suite](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)